# Can't get facebook app approved at Facebook because the app is only available internally

Tags: facebook

I have a facebook user who is the owner of the company I work for.   He has a single Facebook page, which is the "company page" on Facebook.  He created a FB "app" with permissions "manage_pages" and "publish_actions". So the FB api can post to his FB Page, on his behalf, as the app.

Inside the company, we have a few hundred people that use an intranet-based software app.  When the users engage in a certain function in the software, the code uses the Facebook API to post a message to the public company page using an access token of the FB account of the company owner.  This system works great, but the app is not yet approved, so no one can actually see the posts on the FB page except the company owner.

The software is only available inside the company building, it's not reachable via the Internet. There would be serious intellectual property concerns with allowing an anonymous facebook employee into it. There would be security concerns about making this all public on the web. So I have to presume that FB will not be able to see the backend here - where the posts are created.

So because of this, I've run into problems getting the app reviewed because I have no way to let Facebook reviewers actually see the software where the user creates the post, as they requested.

Is this considered a non-starter setup by FB, or does FB have any contingency for this situation? Or do they expect every FB app to be used in a completely public environment? I'm just thinking surely I'm not the only person trying to use a FB app to post to a company page from a publicly-inaccessible place inside that company?

Thanks!

Comment: _“but the app is not yet approved, so no one can actually see the posts on the FB page except the company owner”_ – that is __not__ a matter of approval in review, but simply of the app still being in development mode (it should say so right on top of the first tab in  app dashboard). So just set it “live”. You don’t need to undergo permission review if the only user has a role in the app.

Comment: That was indeed the answer.  Just a misunderstanding of what the settings meant.

Answer (score 0):

This was the answer to the problem, thank you CBroe: It is not a matter of approval that makes the app's postings viewable by everybody, but simply of the app still being in development mode.

The actual Facebook gui in the app dashboard doesn't say "development mode" on/off like it used to.  It now says "do you want to make this app live to the public".  I selected "yes" which made the app's postings viewable by everybody.

In my case, the original confusion stemmed from the fact that we didn't want to make the app live to the public, we only want our one company owner to use the app - so we naturally did not change that setting to "live".